# Hibernate Search- Index not created

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, hibernate-search, hibernate-annotations

i am currently writing my final dissertation in university with the topic of integrating search functionalities into an existing web application and want to use Hibernate Search.

But i am struggling with the indexing of entities in the already existing application.
It seems like the indexing is not working, because no index files are generated when i create a new entity. Also, the base index directory configured in the hibernate configuration is not created when i start the application. 
The application uses the Spring Framework and Hibernate Core with hibernate-jpa 2.0 (see pom.xml).

I get no errors when executing the application, but there is an info concerning Hibernate Search

```
 INFO AnnotationSessionFactoryBean:780 - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
 INFO HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister:75 - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
```

I read that i don´t need to integrate these listeners when using hibernate annotations, so this can´t be the source of the problem, right?

**Extract from pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
       ...
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
         <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
         <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
         <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Extract from applicationContext.xml**

```
<!-- Configuration of Hibernate Session -->
   <bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="de.user.server.model" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${jdbc.debug}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">import.sql</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">28680</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">H:/indexes</prop>

         </props>
      </property>

<!-- hibernate-envers for versioning of entities -->
      <property name="eventListeners">
         <map>
            <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="envers" />
            <entry key="post-update" value-ref="envers" />
            <entry key="post-delete" value-ref="envers" />
            <entry key="pre-collection-update" value-ref="envers" />
            <entry key="pre-collection-remove" value-ref="envers" />
            <entry key="post-collection-recreate" value-ref="envers" />
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

**Text.java**

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Connectable(modelClass = ModelClassEnum.TEXT)
public class Text extends AbstractDataObject {

    /**
     * Value generated automatically by eclipse.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8096234710520978913L;

    private String text;

    public Text() {

    }    

    @Lob
    @Field (name="text",index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES,store=Store.YES)
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }

public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;       
    }
}
```

**AbstractDataObject.java**

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class AbstractDataObject extends BaseDomainModel {
    private Long objectId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @DocumentId
    public Long getObjectId() {
     return objectId;
    }
}
```

I am looking forward to your answers.

Kind regards,
hbsnovice

Comment: The message means that Hibernate Search is not found. Your pom.xml looks like correct, but you say it's a web application. Are you including `hibernate-search-orm` and all its dependencies in the webapp?

Comment: As you can see in the pom.xml of the application, I included the dependency hibernate-search-orm. Or did i missunderstand your question?

Comment: The solution was that the versions of Hibernate ORM and Hibernate Search were not compatible with each other